# Header Not Found in ios Project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6, cocoapods, braintree

I am working on a project where I integrate Braintree. It works fine, but suddenly my Xcode started showing me an error of Missing `Braintree.h`;
Braintree manage by cocoa-pods. I tried updating pods, reinstalling Pods, reinstalling Braintree SDK, and updating the SDK, but all are useless.

Now my code is not compiling.   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i Found they way to solve this Problem

What i did is just simply Delete the workspace file along with the Pods file and folder then re-install the framework via PODS.

because i think information regarding path of SDK's contain in workspace file and very time i delete pods but previous paths not updated may be this is xcode issue.

Answer (score 3):

Clean the project once by pressing `CMD+Alt+Shift+K`, and then try it, if that didn't work:

1. Remove the reference to the file that Xcode thinks it's missing (`Braintree.h`),
2. Then add it again,
3. And clean the project once again,
4. Build and run it.

It must work. If not, attempt closing and reopening the Xcode as well.